# Database having same table name cross database queries In Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have two azure SQL server each having single Database:
Server1 with Database1
Server2 with Database2.
Lets suppose Tables of two Database

Database1 has

- Tbl_A
- Tbl_B
- Tbl_C

Database2 has

- Tbl_A
- Tbl_B

I create external table Tbl_C of Database1 on Database2 and querying Tbl_C from Database2 works fine. Now I want to create external table Tbl_A of Database1  on Database2, how to create and query the cross database having same name? I am using SQL Server Express 2012. Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `SCHEMA_NAME` and `OBJECT_NAME` in the create statement.

> Several important scenarios require the ability to name your external
>   table differently than the original table on the remote database. Any
>   scenario where a local table already exists with the same name as your
>   remote table are examples of that. All of these scenarios require the
>   ability to use an alias for the remote table name

See the example in the image below:

[image]

Reference:
[More Flexible Naming](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/)

Thanks.